# "could be" Vs "could have been" in this case

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

> Question1: What caused the explosion?
> Answer1: The explosion **could have been** caused by a gas leak. (I think this is correct.)
> Answer2: The explosion **could be** caused by a gas leak. (I think this is incorrect.)
>
> Question2: Who stole the money?
> Answer1: It **could have been** Dan, but I’m not sure.  (I think this is correct.)
> Answer2: It **could be** Dan, but I’m not sure.  (I think this is incorrect.)

I think this way because we can only use **could have (done)** to talk about past possibility. Both of the Answer2 do not fit the question. Am I right?

Comment: Don't get too attached to the idea that Past Tense ***It could have been Dan*** is the only "correct" response to a question framed in the Past, such as ***Who did that?*** Native speakers don't necessarily think like that, not least because *the answer is **still currently unknown***. It's quite true that if the addressee *knew* who did it, they'd always reply *It **was** John*, never *It **is** John*. But note that *Who **wanted** ice-cream?* is a perfectly natural question for which ***I do**!* is a perfectly natural response. English tenses are relatively flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two examples are definitely not wrong.

They are both talking about possibilities associated with a definite event in the past that actually occurred, and that is the correct way of talking about them.

Your examples are grammatically correct, but have completely different meaning.

"An explosion could be caused by a gas leak," talks about future possibility of non-specific events rather than a specific past event.

"It could be Dan" talks about what he is right now (potentially a thief) rather than a specific act of theft in the past that he may or may not have committed.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But I didn't get my answer. So I edited my question for you.

Comment: In each pair, the second is NOT grammatically incorrect. It's grammatically correct, but doesn't fit the situation. Grammar is about whether a sentence makes sense, and these do. I don't think your question is improved, and I am no longer sure I know what your question is. If your question is whether the second in each of the first two pairs of examples are grammatically correct: they are. If your question is: do they fit the answer, they do not. However, the second part of your question isn't really related. And "It could be Dan" isn't talking about the future, it's talking about the present.

Comment: So if your question is really about the second half, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Thanks, I get my answer from your above comment. Btw, I deleted the second half.

Answer (score 1):

English has plenty of exceptions and nuances, but in general, yes, your understanding is correct.

One major exception from what you describe is that the perfect aspect is used to describe action that occurs before another action. It can, therefore, be used for future events. For example:

> Today is Monday, and the item hasn't been sold yet. However, you should check again on Thursday, because it **could have been** sold by then.